# Nested loops causing Excel crash

Tags: excel, vba, crash

I am attempting to run a VBA macro that iterates down about 67,000 rows with 100 columns in each row. For each of the cells in these rows, the value is compared against a column with 87 entries in another sheet. There are no errors noted when the code is run but Excel crashes every time. The odd thing is that the code seems to work; I have it set to mark each row in which a match is found and it does so before crashing. I have attempted to run it many times and it has gotten through between 800 and 11,000 rows before crashing, depending on the attempt.

My first suspect was memory overflow due to the volume of calculations but my system shows CPU utilization at 100% and memory usage around 50% while running this code:

```
Sub Verify()

    Dim codes As String
    Dim field As Object

    For i = 2 To Sheets("DSaudit").Rows.Count
        For Each field In Sheets("Dsaudit").Range(Cells(i, 12), Cells(i, 111))
            r = 1
            While r <= 87
                codes = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("287 Denominator CPT").Cells(r, 1).Value
                If field = codes Then
                    Cells(i, 112).Value = "True"
                r = 88
                Else
                    r = r + 1
                End If
            Wend
        Next field
        i = i + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

It should also be noted that I am still very new to VBA so it's likely I've made some sort of egregious rookie mistake. Can I make some alterations to this code to avoid a crash or should I scrap it and take a more efficient approach?

Comment: `Dim field As Object`? Why are declaring this as an `Object`? You should change that to a `Range`. I'm surprised this code even compiles with that declaration, to be honest...

Comment: You want to use arrays and loop that.

Comment: That is because you are doing at least 1 billion iterations, most likely more.  That takes a long time

Comment: @ScottCraner At a glance it looks like it could be 570,438,000 iterations... Which is still a whole lot of iterations...

Comment: ^^ use a column to specify the [last populated row](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm) and use that as an end point, not the total num  of rows in sheet.

Comment: You are testing 98 columns but only have one output column?  Is the point that if any in the row is in the list it is True or all?

Comment: @dwirony how do you figure: 1,048,576 * (111-12) * 87=9,031,385,088

Comment: @ScottCraner Ohh I used 67,000 instead of 1,048,576 - I didn't see that he didn't even use `lastrow`! Wow.

Comment: I am willing to show how to use an array in this instance to speed it up, but I need to know the answer to my question, you are comparing 100 columns to 87 values but only outputing one value.  Does that mean if any of the values in a particular row are found in the list return true, or if all are in the list?  Right now the output turns True if one is found.  Just want to make sure that logic is what is wanted.

Comment: It's not "crashing", it's going "(not responding)" - because it's busy running your nested loops to completion. Let it run long enough (a week, maybe?) and it will eventually complete. Protip: don't iterate cells, ever. Copy only the necessary data into a 2D variant array, and iterate that array instead.

Comment: @ScottCraner Correct, if ANY of the 87 values are found it should output True.

Comment: @dwirony field was originally declared as a range but attempting to run would throw a variable mismatch error in the second for loop stating that field must be either an object or variant. I just tried changing the declaration to an object to match "sheets" and it worked.

Comment: @QHarr Thank you, I'll try and implement lastrow to end the first loop. I need to read up more on arrays before I can attempt implementing one though.

Answer (score 1):

When ever possible iterate variant arrays.  This limits the number of times vba needs to access the worksheet.

Every time the veil between vba and Excel is pierced cost time.  This only pierces that veil 3 times not 9,031,385,088

```
Sub Verify()


    With Sheets("DSaudit")

        'Get last row of Data
        Dim lastrow As Long
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Row 'if column 12 ends before the last row of data change to column that has them all.

        'Load Array with input Values
        Dim rng As Variant
        rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 12), .Cells(lastrow, 111)).Value

        'Create output array
        Dim outpt As Variant
        ReDim outpt(1 To UBound(rng, 1), 1 To 1)

        'Create Match array
        Dim mtch As Variant
        mtch = Worksheets("287 Denominator CPT").Range("A1:A87").Value

        'Loop through first dimension(Row)
        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(rng, 1) To UBound(rng, 1)
            'Loop second dimension(Column)
            Dim j As Long
            For j = LBound(rng, 2) To UBound(rng, 2)
                'Loop Match array
                Dim k As Long
                For k = LBound(mtch, 1) To UBound(mtch, 1)
                    'If eqaul set value in output and exit the inner loop
                    If mtch(k, 1) = rng(i, j) Then
                        outpt(i, 1) = "True"
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next k
                'If filled true then exit this for
                If outpt(i, 1) = "True" Then Exit For
            Next j
        Next i

        'Assign the values to the cells.
        .Cells(2, 112).Resize(UBound(outpt, 1), 1).Value = outpt
    End With

 End Sub
```

Comment: For some reason I'm getting a run-time error '13': Type mismatch on lastrow = .Cells in line 8.
  I've tried applying it to ThisWorkbook, Sheet1, and Module 1 in the project pane but keep getting the same error. Is there somewhere else I should be trying to run this code from?


Also, I really appreciate the help so far. I've had a rough go of trying to teach myself this material in case that isn't abundantly clear already.

Comment: This should be in a module @RayJ

Comment: Line 32 is returning a type mismatch error (13). When I mouse over rng(I, j) it says "rng(i, j) = Error 2023" which google says is a hexadecimal formatting error. Not sure where the type mismatch is coming from as I see both variables are declared as variants. This error also doesn't occur when run stepwise until many iterations through the loop. I'll continue with it tomorrow to see if I can find a solution and report back.

Comment: Then you have errors in your data.  Either fix the data so you do not have errors, which is the preferred method.  Or add a check to skip that item in the array when an error is encountered.  @RayJ  It is always better to fix the underlying data than to use band aids to fix later.

Comment: I was unable to identify what the specific errors were with the input data, however after adding an error handler as a bandaid on line 30 I can confirm that this method does successfully perform the desired action when input errors aren't obstructing it.